# How to create custom Subscriber?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to display `progressDialog` while `observable` is downloading file , and when it's done want to send file to subscriber.

I tried to make my custom subscriber by extends from  `Subscriber` for example:

```
public abstract class MySubscriber<T> extends Subscriber {
    abstract void onMessage(String message);
    abstract void onDownloaded(File file);
}
```

and tried to subscribe with it:
`

```
MySubscriber mySubscriber = new MySubscriber() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                progessDialog.setMessage(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {

            }
        };
```

`observable.subscribe(mySubscriber);`

observable is :

```
observable  = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<Void> subscriber) {
                 //file downloading code...
                if (subscriber instanceof MySubscriber){
                ((MySubscriber) subscriber).onMessage("100%");
                ((MySubscriber) subscriber).onDownloaded(file);
               }else{
                   Log.e(TAG,"subscriber is not instance of MySubscriber")
                }
             }
```

And answer is "subscriber is not instance of MySubscriber"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for `subscriber` not being of type `MySubscriber` is because the instance you pass is eventually wrapped by `subscribe()` in [`SafeSubscriber`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/SafeSubscriber.html):

```java
private static <T> Subscription subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber, Observable<T> observable) {
    ...
        if(!(subscriber instanceof SafeSubscriber)) {
            subscriber = new SafeSubscriber((Subscriber)subscriber);
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

If you want to keep using your approach, you can cast `subscriber` to `SafeSubscriber` and call `SafeSubscriber#getActual()` on it to get your instance of `MySubscriber`.

In your case:

```java
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> subscriber) {
        Subscriber yourSubscriber = ((SafeSubscriber) subscriber).getActual();
        ((MySubscriber) yourSubscriber).onMessage("100%");
        ((MySubscriber) yourSubscriber).onDownloaded(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using below versions,
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
I'm getting ClassCastException OperationSubscriber cannot cast to LoginSubscriber.    
public static abstract class LoginSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
    abstract void onUserNameInvalid(String message);
 }
Above solution doesn't works for me.
Any solution for this @AndroidEx
I was trying to implement below with my custom methods
https://github.com/music60/RxAndroid-MVP-Simple/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/studyjun/rxandroidmvpsimple

Comment: Hey @NickUnuchek can help me in this regards.

Comment: @AbhijitKurane sorry, I didn't work with the answer above.

Comment: I thought it worked for you as you have accepted the answer by AndroidEx.
Thanks for the prompt reply Nick